# Pymongo Query with variable return empty object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to Stackoverflow and I have the exact same issue from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65272885/pymongo-query-with-variables-returns-no-results). This topic is marked as an answer but this doesn't really help me to solve my problem. Do you have a clue about the cause of this problem?

I have this piece of code that return an empty object :

```
tmp = client['test']['Prenom'].aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'annais': 2014, 
            'preusuel': {
                '$ne': '_PRENOMS_RARES'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$preusuel', 
            'nombre': {
                '$sum': '$nombre'
            }, 
            'occurence': {
                '$sum': 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$sort': {
            'nombre': -1
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': 10
    }
])
```

whereas :

```
tmp = client['test']['Prenom'].aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'annais': annee_j, 
            'preusuel': {
                '$ne': '_PRENOMS_RARES'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$preusuel', 
            'nombre': {
                '$sum': '$nombre'
            }, 
            'occurence': {
                '$sum': 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$sort': {
            'nombre': -1
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': 10
    }
])
```

work perfectly and return 10 names.
Thank you

Comment: Include the line where you set `annee_j`? Are you sure it's an `int`?

Comment: Yes it is in a def. And it doesn't even if i define `annee_j` manually it doesn't work

Comment: To compare two values they must be of the same data type. Do you know what is the data type of the field `annais` in the database? You can use the `$type` operator to verify the data type. Note that MongoDB numeric data can be a `double`, `int`, `decimal` or a `long`. In general, the default numeric type is `double` (and this can be different with newer MongoDB v5.0+). With v5.x, the default numeric type is `int` for smaller integers (e.g., `1998`) and a `double` for larger integers (e.g., `12345678900`).

Comment: Can you share the sample data?

Comment: The schema of a document in my collection in MongoDB is : `{"_id":{"$oid":"61d1d0f469fdabbbce5d1789"},"sexe":1,"preusuel":"LEA","annais":1902,"dpt":971,"nombre":3}` I have double checked the type it seems good.